# PHP MAIL WITH ATTACHMENT -- attachment is sent in the form of encoded text not as file

Tags: php

Please anyone help.

I am sending email with attachment in php. email is sent but we do not recieve the attachment as file but it is sent in form of encoded text...any suggestion and help ??

Here is my php code..

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        ob_start();

        if(isset($_FILES['upload_cv']))
    {
    $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['upload_cv']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name        = $_FILES['upload_cv']['name'];
    $file_size        = $_FILES['upload_cv']['size'];
    $file_type        = $_FILES['upload_cv']['type'];
    $file_error       = $_FILES['upload_cv']['error'];
    //$user_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    if($file_error>0)
    {
        die('upload error');
    }
    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
    $handle   = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
    $content  = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents(($content))));
    }
    $boundary = md5("ajantasoya");
    $recipientEmail = "prg6@gmail.com";
    //$senderEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $senderEmail = "vipinmishra.alld@gmail.com";
    $Subject = "Test";
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$boundary."\"\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . " \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$senderEmail." \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$senderEmail." \r\n";
    $headers .= "Subject:". $subject." \r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
    $headers .= "--" . $boundary . " \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" ." \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . " \r\n";
    // Main message start
    $msg_body .= "--" . $boundary . " \r\n";
    $msg_body .= "Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" ." \r\n";
    $msg_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . " \r\n";
    $msg_body  = "Name: ".$_POST['name']. "\r\n"; 
    $msg_body .= "Current Location: ".$_POST['location']. "\r\n"; 
    $msg_body .= "Home town : ".$_POST['home-town']. "\r\n"; 
    $msg_body .= "Marital Status: ".$_POST['mstatus']. "\r\n"; 
    $msg_body .= "Children, if any: ".$_POST['num-ch']. "\r\n"; 
    $msg_body .= "Position applying for : ".$_POST['pos-for']. "\r\n"; 
    $msg_body .= "Date of Birth : ".$_POST['dob']. "\r\n"; 
    $msg_body .= "Strengths: ".$_POST['strenght']. "\r\n"; 
    $msg_body .= "Weaknesses: ".$_POST['weakness']. "\r\n"; 

    //Attachment Part

    $msg_body .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";
    $msg_body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $file_name . "\r\n";
    $msg_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 \r\n";
    $msg_body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment \r\n";

    //$msg_body .="Content-Type: ".$file_type. ";  Name=".$file_name."\r\n";
    //$msg_body .="Content-Type: ".$file_type. ";  Name=".$file_name."\r\n";
    //$msg_body .="Content-Disposition: Attachment;       Filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
    //$msg_body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $msg_body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
    $msg_body .= $encoded_content;

    $message = $msg_body;
    $send = @mail($recipientEmail, $Subject , $message, $headers);
    if ($send) {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
    else {
        echo "ERROR sending message.";
    }

}
ob_end_flush();     
?>
```

Comment: try save file first to disk. then attached it from saving path

Comment: The filename should be in the `Content-Disposition:` field, not `Content-type:`. And it should be `filename=`, not `name=`.

Comment: Thanks... i tried after saving on server but still same problem...

Answer (score 0):

In the header, you have:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$boundary."\"\r\n";
```

So the boundary between the message and the attachment should be `--PHP-mixed-$boundary`. But when you encode the message body, you're sending:

```
$msg_body .= "--" . $boundary . " \r\n";
```

You're missing the `PHP-mixed-` prefix before `$boundary`. Change those lines to:

```
$msg_body .= "--PHP-mixed-" . $boundary . " \r\n";
```

Also, you're not specifying the filename in the correct place in the attachment header. You have it in the `Content-type:` line, it should be in `Content-disposition:`.

```
$msg_body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream \r\n";
$msg_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 \r\n";
$msg_body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"  \r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for yr reply...I tried but still have same problem here is my complete code can u please correct it and post .....

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
            ob_start();

            if(isset($_FILES['upload_cv']))
        {
        $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['upload_cv']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name        = $_FILES['upload_cv']['name'];
        $file_size        = $_FILES['upload_cv']['size'];
        $file_type        = $_FILES['upload_cv']['type'];
        $file_error       = $_FILES['upload_cv']['error'];
        //$user_email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        if($file_error>0)
        {
            die('upload error');
        }
        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle   = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
        $content  = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        $boundary = md5("ajantasoya");
        }


        $recipientEmail = "prg6@gmail.com";
        //$senderEmail = $_POST['email'];
        $senderEmail = "prg5@gmail.com";
        $Subject = "Test";
        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
        $headers .= "From: ".$senderEmail." \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$senderEmail." \r\n";
        $headers .= "Subject:". $subject." \r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
        $msg_body  = "Name: ".$_POST['name']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Current Location: ".$_POST['location']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Home town : ".$_POST['home-town']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Marital Status: ".$_POST['mstatus']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Children, if any: ".$_POST['num-ch']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Position applying for : ".$_POST['pos-for']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Date of Birth : ".$_POST['dob']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Qualifications : \r\n \r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "             Stream      "; 
        $msg_body .= "Year of Completion      "; 
        $msg_body .= "Percentage      \r\n \r\n";  
        $msg_body .= "Others      "; 
        $msg_body .= $_POST['other-e']."      ";
        $msg_body .= $_POST['other-y']."      ";
        $msg_body .= $_POST['other-p']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Masters      "; 
        $msg_body .= $_POST['master-e']."      ";
        $msg_body .= $_POST['master-y']."      ";
        $msg_body .= $_POST['master-p']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Bachelors      "; 
        $msg_body .= $_POST['bachlor-e']."      ";
        $msg_body .= $_POST['bachlor-y']."      ";
        $msg_body .= $_POST['bachlor-p']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "HSC            "; 
        $msg_body .= $_POST['hse-e']."      ";
        $msg_body .= $_POST['hse-y']."      ";
        $msg_body .= $_POST['hse-p']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "SSC            "; 
        $msg_body .= $_POST['ssc-e']."      ";
        $msg_body .= $_POST['ssc-y']."      ";
        $msg_body .= $_POST['ssc-p']. "\r\n";
            $tot_emp_details = sizeof($_POST['cname']);
        //echo $tot_emp;

        $msg_body .= "Strengths: ".$_POST['strenght']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Weaknesses: ".$_POST['weakness']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Where do you see yourself in 5 years?: ".$_POST['next-5-year']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Where do you see yourself in 10 years?: ".$_POST['next-10-year']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "What is your eventual career goal?: ".$_POST['career-goal']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Computer skills: ".$_POST['computer']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Languages: ".$_POST['language']. "\r\n"; 
        $msg_body .= "Others, if any: ".$_POST['other-any']. "\r\n"; 
            //Attachment Part
            $msg_body .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";
            //$msg_body .="Content-Type: ".$file_type. ";  Name=".$file_name."\r\n";
            $msg_body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream \r\n";
            $msg_body .="Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
            $msg_body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $msg_body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
            $msg_body .= $encoded_content;

        $message = $msg_body;
        $send = @mail($recipientEmail, $Subject , $message, $headers);
        if ($send) {
            echo "Message sent!";
        }
        else {
            echo "ERROR sending message.";
        }

    }
    ob_end_flush();     
    ?>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or a continuation of the question? If it's part of the question, add it to the question by clicking the "edit" link, don't post it as an answer.

Comment: You're missing the `multipart/mixed` content type in the header.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly how it should look like. The parts you might be missing **

```
           $eol = "\n";
           // main header (multipart mandatory)
           $headers = "From: $form". $eol;
           $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
           **$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"";**

           // message
            $body .= "--$boundary" . $eol;
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol.$eol;
            $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;
            $body .= "--".$boundary.$eol;
            $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
            $body .= $message.$eol;

            //attachment
            $body .= "--$boundary" . $eol;
            $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
            $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment". $eol.$eol;
            $body .= $content . $eol;
            **$body .= "--$boundary--";**

            mail('email', 'subject', $body, $headers)
```